# Troubleshooting help with the Magento Responsive Web Design Developer's Guide tutorial

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, scss

Can't for the life of me get my store to work with the custompackage/customtheme I created in this tutorial:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide

I SSH'd into my server that has a brand new install of Magento 1.9.1, then used the exact commands given in the tutorial to create the new directories and copy the files over from the rwd theme. After that, I downloaded the new /scss directory onto my Windows machine and used Scout to generate the css files, and then uploaded those to my server at /skin/frontend/custompackage/customtheme/css.

As soon as I update the System->Configuration->General->Design->Package and Theme settings in Magento to custompackage and customtheme, I get the "There has been an error processing your request" Magento error page when I try to load my home page.

Anyone have any idea what sort of mistake I could have made to cause that error?

Thanks!

Edit-  Here is the exception and backtrace generated by Magento:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:24:"Not valid template file:";i:1;s:4309:"  
0 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer->_toHtml()  
1 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()  
2 /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml(34): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu->getHtml('level-top')  
3 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/*/...')  
4 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')  
5 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()  
6 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()  
7 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()  
8 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()  
9 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()  
10 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topMenu', true)  
11 /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml(46): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topMenu')  
12 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/*/...')  
13 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')  
14 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()  
15 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()  
16 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()  
17 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)  
18 /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(42): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')  
19 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/*/...')  
20 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')  
21 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()  
22 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()  
23 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()  
24 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()  
25 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()  
26 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')  
27 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')  
28 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()  
29 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')  
30 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))  
31 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()  
32 /public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)  
33 /public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')  
34 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Here are the templates that I got when I made this call:

```
grep -E '(catalog/navigation|page/html/topmenu)' app/design/frontend/*/*/layout/*.xml
```

`template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"`
`template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"`
`template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"`
`template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"`

When I call

```
find app/design/frontend -path '*/template/path/to/template.html'
```

with those paths, I am able to find each of the templates referenced.  They all exist in `/frontend/rwd`, except `"top.phtml"` which is only in `/frontend/base` and `/frontend/default`.

Why would this error exist once I switch to custompackage and customtheme, but not exist when I have package and theme both set to rwd?  My `/frontend/custompackage` directory only contains `/customtheme/etc/theme.xml` which, as per the tutorial, reads as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<theme>  
<parent>rwd/default</parent> 
</theme>
```

Comment: That page generates a report in var/report. It contains the exception and backtrace.

Comment: Thanks - I added the report to the question.  From it I understand that customtheme isn't a valid theme, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means you are missing the template file for the category menu. Your theme defines a template for it, but it's not installed.

To find out which template it's looking for, you can try:

```
grep -E '(catalog/navigation|page/html/topmenu)' app/design/frontend/*/*/layout/*.xml
```

Look for `template="path/to/template.phtml"` in the output and try to locate each file using:

```
find app/design/frontend -path '*/template/path/to/template.html'
```

This is the non invasive way. If that yields no results, you will need to insert a debug statement into the core file `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Html/Topmenu/Renderer.php`. The exception is really there, not sure why the backtrace in the report is incomplete. Starting from line 52, insert two debug statements:

```
    $includeFilePath = realpath(Mage::getBaseDir('design') . DS . $this->getTemplateFile());
    Mage::log('Resolving template '.$includeFilePath, null, 'template.log', true); // Debug line 1
    if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath(Mage::getBaseDir('design'))) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {
        $this->_templateFile = $includeFilePath;
    } else {
        Mage::log('Design base dir not at start but at index: ', strpos($includeFilePath, realpath(Mage::getBaseDir('design'))), null, 'template.log', true); // Debug line two
        throw new Exception('Not valid template file:' . $this->_templateFile);
    }
```

This will create a file template.log in the `var/log` directory. From the looks of it, there are symlinks involved or at least the checks here assume that based on the strpos() outcome. Very interesting to see the results.

Ok, you accepted the answer so you found the error. In my stock 1.9.0.1 install there's `./app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml`. For some reason your theme.xml is not respected. Cache can be an issue here. But with the information provided in the question, it seems you did everything right :).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I've added the paths/files that get returned by those calls to my original post.  I'll try adding that debug line now, but I would think whatever mistake I made in following the tutorial would result in something very fundamentally wrong with my package/theme structure.

Comment: Well, the top.phtml is your problem. You're setting the parent to rwd/default, so top.phtml has to exist either in custompackage/customtheme or rwd/default. Allthough I would expect it to still fallback to base/default, it seems it doesn't. Verify with the debug code and then look in `app/design/frontend/custompackage/customtheme/layout/*.xml` where that file is referenced.

Comment: The tutorial didn't call for a `customtheme/layout/` directory.  The only file in `app/design/frontend/custompackage/custometheme/` is `/etc/theme.xml`.  The tutorial I'm referencing is here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide#theme-compass

Comment: I'm not able to get the path with a debug function.  The function that line 919 of Abstract.php is in is called toHtml().  As best I can tell it doesn't reference the path of a template.  The only variables set before line 919 are $html and $translate.  Let me know if you want me to put the function in my main post.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Those debug lines create two files in the `/var/log` directory.  The first file is called `template.log` and it contains this line: `2014-12-10T01:27:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): Resolving template`.  The second file is called `system.log` and it contains this line `2014-12-10T01:27:34+00:00 EMERG (): Design base dir not at start but at index:`.

Comment: When I use var_export instead if Mage::log it tells me that $includeFilePath is not an object.

Comment: The 2nd line has comma where it should be a dot after the string. But clearly, $includeFilePath is false, which realpath() does if the path doesn't exist. So change that line to read ` Mage::log('Resolving template '.$includeFilePath.' based on '.$this->getTemplateFile(), null, 'template.log', true); // Debug line 1`

Comment: `2014-12-10T02:01:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): Resolving template  based on frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml`

Comment: There is no `/html/topmenu`.  When I create one and put the `renderer.phtml` from `rwd/template/page/html/topmenu` there the page loads.  It doesn't look the same as the rwd theme that the tutorial was supposed to be replicating and I still have no idea where I went wrong in following that tutorial - but thank you for being so patient, teaching me some debugging, and tracking down the issue that was preventing the store from loading!

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know exactly went wrong with using Scout to compile the css, but when I tried the same tutorial on a dedicated server with Compass/Sass installed and used the `watch` command everything worked as it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a line in the stack trace of the error that mentions Layout.php line 555. Please check out one of my answered questions about this line. Just in case, because it can solve your problem immediately. The answers is in the PHP 7 to PHP 5 compatibility with uniform variable syntax. See `https://www.atwix.com/magento/magento-and-php-7/` and `https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax` .